# How to skip Chrome Welcome screen, every time I run Appium, Ruby test

Tags: android, ruby, appium

I'm new to Appium. So my requirement is to run web driver test through Appium in simulator but when I run every time chrome always shows the welcome screen which I have to manually skip to see the test result and take screen shots. How to skip the chrome welcome screen?

Below is my settings
Appium 1.5.3
Mobile platform/version under test: Android 7.1
Real device or emulator/simulator: Emulator

This is what I have in my env.rb file

```
begin
  system 'adb uninstall io.appium.settings'
  system 'adb uninstall io.appium.unlock'
  $driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps).start_driver
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.message
  Process.exit(0)  
 end
else # else create driver instance for desktop browser
 begin
   $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:"#{$browser_type}")
   $driver.manage().window().maximize()
 rescue Exception => e
   puts e.message
   Process.exit(0)
 end
end
```

Comment: You can try with directly navigating to other page on browser startup. Like: `$driver.manage().window().maximize()                                      $driver.navigate.to "http://google.com" `

Comment: @peterpawar this won't help.. tried adb that shoudl directly open url in default browser, but without luck `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://seznam.cz`

Answer (score 1):

Enable USB debugging in "Developer options". This is strange but it works. Refer below url for more details
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6618

Comment: Yep it's strange, but I confirm that it works, I'm using selenuim (python) & memu emulator, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert 'chromeOptions' to your desired cap dict. That worked for me! '--disable-free' argument will disable welcome screen for your chrome browser.
Check here for more details: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md

```
desired_cap = {
            "platformName": "Android",
            "deviceName": "AppiumP",
            'appPackage': 'com.android.chrome',
            'appActivity': 'com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main',
            'chromeOptions': {
                'args': ['--disable-fre']
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After my test, I can say allowing debugging is a right way to skip the Chrome welcome screen.

**Test environment**

- Appium Desktop 1.22.0
- LDPlayer 4.0.73(64), Android 7.1.2
- Chrome 95(shipping with the system)

**Steps**

1. Create a new emulator
2. In emulator settings, enable `ADB debugging`
   [image: Emulator Settings Window]
3. Boot into the system
4. Enable `USB debugging` in `Developer options`
5. Start a new Remote driver with the following capabilities

```
desired_caps = {'platformName': 'Android',
                'platformVersion': '7.1.2',
                'deviceName': 'emulator-5554',
                'chromeOptions': {'w3c': False},    # avoid invalid locator
                'browserName': 'Chrome',            # either browserName or appPackage must be specified
                'newCommandTimeout': 0,             # do not auto exit
                }
```

That's all I do before starting a new Remote driver, and there's nothing involved with "skipping welcome screen" in `desired_caps`.

So if I start Chrome this way, it would go straight to a blank page of URL `data:,`. You can check the difference just by turning on/off `USB debugging` from system settings.

**If you happen to use ldplayer like me**

1. You can use `ld -s 0 settings put global adb_enabled 1` to enable `USB debugging`. `ld.exe` is located in the installation folder of LDPlayer, and `0` is the index of the emulator you are working on, which can be found in `LDMultiPlayer` right next to the check box(You can use `ldconsole.exe list2` to get a full list of emulator details in your device).
2. You can enable `ADB debugging` by modifying the value of `"basicSettings.adbDebug"` in per emulator config file which is storing in `<LDPlayer_Installation_Folder>\vms\config`.

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck at the same issue from past 3 days. You need to enable USB debugging on your simulator to get rid of the welcome screen on chrome. Follow these steps:

1. Open settings on your simulator
2. Tap on About emulated device
3. Tap 7 times on the Build Number to enable Developer options
4. Go back to the setting main page
5. Click on Developer options
6. Allow USB debugging

Rerun your script. You should NOT see the Welcome screen on chrome again. Good Day !!