# Skipping Chrome Welcome Pase in Emulated Android using Eclipse and Appium Desktop?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, android-studio, appium, appium-desktop

I'm trying to run an Eclipse java script in order to automate a Web Application using Appium Desktop and Android Emulator.

The script's aim is only to open the Chrome browser in the Android Emulator and go to a specific URL:

```
package Appium.appiumTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class chrometest {

AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus5");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("https://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.get("URL");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public void searchKeyword() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    chrometest obj = new chrometest();
    obj.setUp();

}
}
```

When running the application with the Appium server running, the chrome browser opens at the emulated android, although the welcome page is constantly opening. After three/four attempts, the following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An 
unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original 
error: Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be 
created. (Original error: session not created exception: Chrome version must 
be >= 60.0.3112.0
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 
(e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 
x86_64)) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I have tried to upgrade the chrome browser in the emulated android using the Play Store, but it does not let me log in, so that's not an option.

Comment: As I understand you have to update the Chrome version, consider the line `Chrome version must 
be >= 60.0.3112.0`

Comment: I have tried updating the Chrome version, but I cannot update it on the Android Emulator, as the Play Store page does not load. I also tried dragging the apk of the chrome version but then the chrome does not respond on the emulator.

Comment: Yeah, I understand if you really want to do with emulator, so you can try it https://www.genymotion.com/blog/2-10-open-gapps-widget/

Answer (score 0):

You can skip this step by Allowing USB debugging in your emulator. I was stuck at this welcome screen but this workaround helped.

Detailed steps are available in this question - [How to skip Chrome Welcome screen, every time I run Appium, Ruby test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843838/how-to-skip-chrome-welcome-screen-every-time-i-run-appium-ruby-test)